# xcode missing all distribution profiles, entitlements.

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, ios-provisioning

New to Xcode 5, all talk about how easy everything is. However, it seams as though I have no choices for Choosing my profile for distribution, My certificate is current, I made a dsitribution profile, my bundle ID matches the App, but I only get a developer profile, I can't toggle or change the values, They seem locked, Any thought on what is causing this, so frustrated. Ugh. I think I need to relearn this entire process. Tutorial recommendations for xcode 5?

Thanks

[image: BuildSettings]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 can automatically create these certificates for you. You can go to Xcode preferences -> Accounts -> Select your Dev Account -> View Details -> Add iOS Distribution Signing Identity

[image]

Comment: Thanks,I have those but the target doesn't let me change anything in the above sections.

Comment: Did you try switching to combined view in Build Settings?